# C Makefile - recompile only changed files

Tags: makefile

Hello I have a shared library libnsd.so (made up of nsd.c,nsd.h,nd.c,nd.h) linked to main file.
My question is how to write the makefile so that it recompiles only those source files that have been changed.
I have read some topics about this but got somewhat confused, I'm a beginner programmer.
My makefile code so far:

```
CC=gcc

all : lib alll

alll : main.c   
    $(CC) main.c -o main -L. libnsd.so

lib : nsd.c nsd.h nd.c nd.h
    $(CC) -c -fPIC nsd.c -o nsd.o
    $(CC) -c -fPIC nd.c -o nd.o
    $(CC) -shared -Wl,-soname,libnsd.so -o libnsd.so  nsd.o nd.o

clean:
    rm main libnsd.so nd.o nsd.o
```

Comment: You need to have the target have the same name as the output file that youdon't want recompiled

Comment: (that is, don't have a target call commands that don't create a file with the same name as the target)

Comment: You'd have nsd.o, nd.o, libnsd.so, main as individual targets

Comment: yes, thanks i got it. :)

Comment: @PaulStelian Please add that as the answer and elaborate a bit. Petr you should either accept the answer, if Paul posts one, or post your own answer. Answering your own answer is encouraged.

Comment: @2501 I have posted an answer, hope it is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makefiles have the concept of build targets. The build targets are, really, all the intermediate as well as the final files and, by the way they are written, they can be made to use dependencies.

A sample solution for your makefile:

```
CC=gcc

all: main

main: main.c libnsd.so
    $(CC) main.c -o main -L. libnsd.so

libnsd.so: nsd.o nd.o
    $(CC) -shared -Wl,-soname,libnsd.so -o libnsd.so $@

%.o: %.c nsd.h nd.h
    $(CC) -c -fPIC $< -o $@
```

A few things to note:

1. You should properly correct my dependencies on the object file creation (since I consider that each of the C files depends on both of the headers).
2. You may wish to note the wildcard construction I have used...
3. If there was nothing special with some of these commands I could have left default commands work. Do note that I have used `$<` for the first dependency and `$@` for the output in the wildcard rule.
4. I haven't copied the `clean` rule, since it was written correctly in the question itself.

Each of the targets (besides the "phony" target `all`) creates a file with the same name: The target `libnsd.so` creates a file with the name `libnsd.so`. The target `main` creates a file with the name `main`.

As a dependency of a target changes date so that the dependency is newer than the output, `make` will recreate the target, as well as other targets that depend on it. But if you have a target that is not mapped to any output file, that target is always called (in our code, the `all` target is always called but thankfully it has no commands and it depends only on actual files which may or may not need being recreated)

Do note that GNU Make doesn't need to have compiling in particular. The creation of an output file can happen by *any* means, and indeed I have seen a target create a `.cpio.gz` archive. But if that archive is older than any of the dependencies (the folder it would pack in) then it would be recreated, according to `make`.

Comment: As additional comments, my target `all` corresponds to your target `all`, my target `main` also corresponds to your target `all` (your target `all1` doesn't obey dependencies so it's not represented) while your target `lib` is represented via my target `libsnd.so`. Also, for compiling .c to .o files I have written a wildcard rule. There are various other ways to make the rule more resilient to renames of the targets but back in 2017 I only knew so much.